# error memory read failed for 0*0 XCode 8 beta crashing in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10, xcode8

I converted my project written in Swift 2.2 to swift 2.3 to run in Xcode 8 beta. But the app is crashing when calling  the webservice giving the "error memory read failed for 0*0" without giving any further information. I think it will be a problem with completion handler block or error in NSURLSession.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well, in an objective-c app on Xcode 8.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: The solution for me was to quit Xcode and trash the contents of Xcode's "Derived Data" folder before relaunch.